# How to access gcloud secret using Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, google-cloud-platform

I need to pick up client secrets from google cloud using below command.

```
gcloud secrets versions access latest --project=test --secret=test
```

How do I run the same command using Java Code in my selenium tests

Answer (score 0):

According to the [**google official documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets#secretmanager-create-secret-java) first you need to follow a few steps.

> Enable secret manager API
>
> Assign the Secret Manager Admin role (roles/secretmanager.admin) on the project, folder, or organization.
>
> Set up a Java development environment and install the Secret Manager
> Java SDK. On Compute Engine or GKE, you must authenticate with the
> cloud-platform scope.

Then by using `GetSecret.java` class you can access the secrets. This [**github repository**](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/e13fbccca9754d9da34463dd12212c66de809f03/secretmanager/src/main/java/secretmanager) contains a full list of classes available using this as a reference you can write your own snippets. Hope this will help you.

Comment: @azhar is your issue resolved.. revert back if you are still facing the issues..